# Django in sub-directory

Tags: python, django, url

When i build my django application, i'll use the runserver command in order to test my website, but in deploy, let's say that i'll publish my website under: www.test.com/django.

My IIS it's configure with an application under my default website called "django".

I'm expecting that everything will works fine, but django doesn't recognize my url schema, that is the following one:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
]
```

and in this case, i need to modify my urlpatterns like this, in order to serve the application via www.test.com/django:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?i)django/', include([ #Application name
        # Examples:
        url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
        url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about'),
    ])),
]
```

It's a good approach? it's working but i'm not sure about the quality of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method to fix this is to have your webserver pass the `SCRIPT_NAME` wsgi variable. Django will automatically use this variable as a prefix when constructing urls, without the need to change your url configuration. I'm unfamiliar with IIS, so I can't tell you how to do this. It does have the advantage that your code is completely agnostic to the actual mount point of your WSGI application, as the script name is passed to Django rather than configured in its settings.

Alternatively, you can set the [`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#force-script-name) setting to `/django/`.

Comment: Ok, tested right now, so, in debug i have to put the include with the current name? because if not, i can't test the subdirectory on my own local debug server, right?

But the, url interpolation (using url template tags now works as expected!) using FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME!

Comment: @VirtApp You should only set `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/django/'` in your production settings, not in your development settings.

Comment: I know, but in my development server i need to simulate that directory, so i need to add something like that with a conditional if about the debug settings or not, right?:


`urlpatterns2 = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'yourapp.views.home', name='Home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^django/', include(urlpatterns2)),
)`

Comment: Why do you need the `/django/` prefix in development? It sounds to me like you want to test `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` -- which already has extensive coverage in Django's own test suite.

Comment: Maybe i'm not explaining good, it's ok, but with this approach if i try to go to:  http://127.0.0.1/django nothing works, i mean, the urls will be resolved with the force_script_name (ex.: http://127.0.0.1/django/get_cities...and they doesn't work), but if i try to go to my homepage (http://127.0.0.1/django), nothing works.

At this time, the only working solution that does the job is the only one that i'll wrote in the first post.

Comment: But you shouldn't use `127.0.0.1/django/` in development, you should use `127.0.0.1/`, and you souldn't set the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` setting in development. Only in production do you use the `/django/` prefix.

Comment: I've got a situation where I need to run dev server at a non root directory.  I've got code-server running in my kubernetes cluster for remote cloud development.  I've got a bunch of dev ENVs setup at `ourcompany.dev/username/`. I can't host them all at `ourcompany.dev` obviously.