# Running django web app over a web path in a sandbox

Tags: django, web

At the place where I work we have the option to deploy applications through a sandbox. With that a problem arises and that is that for each application running we have a web path, for example:

*domain.com/path/of/app_django/*.

With that base path I can access the main view of my application (*0.0.0.0:8080/* **>>** *domain.com/path/of/app_django/*) however when trying to access other views django uses the main domain, for example *domain.com*/**my_url** instead of being *domain.com/path/of/app_django*/**my_url**. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856091/4151233